# If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, prove that $2f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, prove that $2f$ is integrable.

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, if $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, there is some partition $P = \{x_{0}, \ldots x_{n}\}$ of $[a, b]$ such that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$.

Then, for any $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots n\}$, if we define $M_{i}(f) = \text{sup}\{f(x) \mid x \in  [x_{i-1}, x_{i}] \}$ and $m_{i}(f) = \text{inf}\{f(x) \mid x \in  [x_{i - 1}, x_{i}] \}$, we get

$$U(2f, P) - L(2f, P) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(M_{i}(2f) - m_{i}(2f)) \Delta x_{i} = 2 \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (M_{i}(f) - m_{i}(f)) \Delta x_{i} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (M_{i}(f) - m_{i}(f))\Delta x_{i} = U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon.$$

I need to show that this is less than $\epsilon$ how can I do it?

Comment: Prove $M_i(2f)=2\cdot M_i(f)$ using definition.

Comment: ohhhhhh i see it now, thanks. o

Comment: if you post the answer i will give it to you @YadatiKiran

Comment: Haha! Thanks anyways. I am only trying to help you not solve for you.

Comment: This is too obvious if one considers Riemann sums. Any Riemann sum of $2f$ is twice a Riemann sum of $f$ over same partitions and hence integral of $2f$ is twice the integral of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show that $$\sup \{2a \mid a \in A\} = 2 \sup \{a \mid  a \in A\} \quad \text{and} \quad \inf \{2a \mid  a \in A\} = 2 \inf \{a \mid  a \in A\}$$
using the definition of supremum and infimum.  Thus
$$M_i(2f) - m_i(2f) = 2M_i(f) - 2m_i(f) = 2(M_i(f) - m_i(f))$$ giving you
$$U(2f,P) - L(2f,P) = 2(U(f,P) - L(f,P)).$$